# How can i send data from external page to salesforce visualforce page without salesforce authentication

Tags: visualforce, integration, xml

I am trying to create a Visualforce page and a controller to receive request from an external web page . This external page will send an XML file to my page and I have to using controller to get this file. The problem here is how to create the Visualforce that allows the external page bypass salesforce authentication and send data to my page, and how can I receive the XML file from it on controller.

If you have any solution or example code for this case, it will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered writing a SOAP or REST web service ? Having unauthenticated integration is very very bad practise, I'd urge you to reconsider that idea.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I also think about Rest API, but customer ask me to do with VS page and Controller

Answer (score 1):

A [Force.com Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) allows for unauthenticated access. All access is done via a special "Site Guest User" user that has a dedicated profile that you add your page to.

Instead of a controller and Visualforce page, you could instead write an Apex class annotated with [@RestResource](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST) that has an @HttpPost method. That method would need to convert the incoming XML data into an SObject and insert that SObject for use by other parts of your application. The class must be added to the dedicated profile.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I will talk with my customer about this approach.